# Modify image data in ByteBuffer

Tags: java, opengl, png, bytebuffer

I would like to modify the per-pixel RGB color data of a PNG image that I have loaded as a `ByteBuffer`, preferably a simple, lightweight solution.

I currently load the data directly from the file into a `ByteBuffer` using a `ReadableByteChannel`, which does **not** decode the PNG data.

So the question is, how do I

1. Decode the `ByteBuffer` PNG data into something where I can modify the pixel data
2. Turn it back into a valid `ByteBuffer` ('valid' means that it would be accepted by an OpenGl shader)

Comment: You have to decode the png in any way before passing it to OpenGL.

Comment: @BDL Fair enough, I suppose I need it in a format that NanoVG understands.

Comment: Why are you reading an encoded png blob to a byte buffer in the first place?

Comment: @derhass I thought that was what I was supposed to do? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: use some image loader which actually understands the file formats you wanna use

Comment: @Rabbid76 I would prefer not to use AWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PNG image encoding includes (among other things) a ZLIB compression, you cannot access the pixel values directly. You need (practically speaking) to decode the image, for example reading it into a [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) with `ImageIO.read( )`

If for some reason (huge image, memory constraints) you don't like to load the full image in memory in a `BufferedImage` you could use a progressive reader (eg [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj))